# Simplify type definition with keyof (interface)?

Tags: typescript, type-definition

I have an interface which looks like this:

```
declare global  {
    namespace Express {
        interface Request {
            db: {
              User: Repository<User>,
              Product: Repository<Product>
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to change `db` into somthing dynamically? with `keyof`?
So I don't have to change the Interface on every database change.

Answer (score 0):

You could, by making db of type `any`. You could also choose to make your interface a generic interface (Request), which would be nicer imho...

What exactly are you trying to do? An interface is just for designing a contract, not for dynamic behaviour...